# heroku postgres :: How many databases are allowed per plan (production: crane)?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, cloud

We are considering Heroku Postgres Crane plan. Anyone knows how many databases can be created in one such plan? Could not get this info anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Each plan provides only one db. You can have multiple postgres addons to get multiple dbs, but you will be billed per plan/addon. I would recommend using multiple tables instead of multiple dbs for your app.

If you wish to use multiple plans, you can have an unlimited number of dbs per account, but currently, only about ~30 dbs per app before Heroku runs out of identifiers.